# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error (says invalid web.config, but its valid)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-8, asp.net-core-2.1

This is on a brand new server running windows 2016, installed the hosting bundle, set the app pool to no managed.
[image]

Here is my web.config (generated by vs, using a default, nothing changed asp.net 2.0 web app)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
   </handlers>
 <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had not installed the hosting bundle properly.. now its installed properly it all works